# How to find out if anyone has done git rebase operation in remote branch?

Tags: git, git-rebase, git-stash

An important commit is missing from commit history of remote git repository.
Is there any way to find out who did git rebase in that particular remote branch?

Comment: You would know if someone rebased a remote commit or branch. A horrible merge conflict would result while pulling.

Comment: How to know the author who did rebase?

Answer (score 0):

Each time you do a rebase Git changes the commiter information and date. If no other rebase has taken place, you could look for discrepancies in author/commiter in each commit of that branch

Comment: In fact, as they seem to know which commit is missing, simply look at the commits immediately before/after the "ghost commit", and the culprit should be right there.